# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Below is my models.py

```
from . import db

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__='Products'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    brandname=db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True)
    description=db.Column(db.String(500),nullable=False)
    price=db.Column(db.Float,nullable=False)
    image=db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,default='defaultproduct.jpg')

    def __repr__(self):
        str = "Id: {}, brandname: {}, description: {}, price: {}, image: {} \n"
        str = str.format(self.id,self.brandname,self.description,self.price,self.image)
        return str
```

below is my views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, url_for , request , session
from .models import Product

bp = Blueprint('main',__name__)

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    products= Product.query.order_by(Product.brandname).all()
    return render_template('Home.html',products=products)
```

when I try to run the project I get error like
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'query'"

Can anyone helpme to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Python class structures properly. Your `Product` class has no attribute `query`, meaning that "query" is a meaningless statement in the class `Product`.
If you want to be able to use `query` in `Product` you must first define it in the `Product` class, for example:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__='Products'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    brandname=db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True)
    description=db.Column(db.String(500),nullable=False)
    price=db.Column(db.Float,nullable=False)
    query = some_value
    image=db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,default='defaultproduct.jpg')
```

Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying use Python as a DBMS, which it is not. You do not need to "query" anything in a class, you simply reference it by the following logic: Class.attribute.

Please read the Python documentation on classes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html